# Files are not visible in Site Content and Structure

Tags: sharepoint-designer, publishing-site, sharepoint-foundation

I have a CSS and bunch of images that are not visible when using Site Content and Structure but are visible via SPD?

I'm guessing something to do with ghosting?

The CSS files were deployed via a feature and are in Site Assets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done. Don't know how it got fixed though - the developer sent me new version :) sorry

Answer (score 0):

Can you please show the Module and it's File elements. Do you have Type="GhostableInLibrary" on the File elements?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
- <Module Name="SliderLayout" Url="SiteAssets/IIA/Slider">
  <File Path="SliderLayout\Script.js" Url="Scripts/slider.js" Type="GhostableInLibrary" />